# How to convert eigen::Transform to tf2::Transform and vice versa in ROS C++?

Tags: c++, eigen, ros, tf2-ros

How can i convert between types in eigen and tf2 ?

```cpp
Eigen::Transform Tf2ToEigen(const tf2::Transform& in)
{
    eigen::Transform out;
    tf2::convert(in, out);
    return out;
}

tf2::Transform EigenToTf2(const Eigen::Transform& in)
{
    tf2::Transform out;
    tf2::convert(in, out);
    return out;
}
```

tf2::convert above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this just a typo? Did you try `Eigen` instead of `eigen`? Also provide a [mre], you may be missing some includes.

Comment: yep thanks! its just a typo, it tried both but no luck..

Comment: @Bader Which dependencies have you added to your `CMakeLists.txt`? Which headers are you including?